# How to return NULL values in MySQL query if no results in LEFT JOIN and WHERE clause are found

Tags: mysql, sql, database, left-join, inner-join

I have a problem with a MySQL query.

Here are my three tables:

employees:

```
    id  initials  deleted  
------  --------  ---------
     1  TV                0
     2  AH                0
     3  JE                0
     4  MA                0
     5  MJ                0
     6  CE                0
     7  KB                1
     8  KL                1
```

Schedule :

```
    id  place                         start                  end  deleted  
------  --------------  -------------------  -------------------  ---------
     1  Somewhere       2018-05-11 16:48:17  2018-05-15 16:48:26          0
     2  Somewhere else  2018-05-12 16:48:50  2018-05-14 16:48:55          1
     3  Here            2018-05-13 00:00:00  2018-05-13 00:00:00          0
     4  Not here        2018-05-18 16:49:42  2018-05-16 16:49:48          0
```

And schedule_link :

```
    id  id_employee  id_schedule  
------  -----------  -------------
     1            1              1
     2            1              2
     3            4              3
     4            5              4
```

I would like a request that returns all that is concerned by the date of the day for each employee. Even if the employee does not have any records found, I would like the query to return its initials with NULL in the other columns.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT
  `employees`.`id`,
  `employees`.`initials`,
  `schedule`.`place`,
  `schedule`.`start`,
  `schedule`.`end`,
  `schedule`.`deleted`
FROM
  `employees`
  LEFT JOIN `schedule_link`
    ON (
      `employees`.`id` = `schedule_link`.`id_employee`
    )
  LEFT JOIN `schedule`
    ON (
      `schedule_link`.`id_schedule` = `schedule`.`id`
    )
WHERE (
    `employees`.`deleted` = '0'
    AND `schedule`.`deleted` = '0'
  )
  AND (
    DATE(CURDATE()) BETWEEN CAST(schedule.start AS DATE)
    AND CAST(schedule.end AS DATE)
  )
```

This returns me the following data:

```
    id  initials  place                    start                  end  deleted  
------  --------  ---------  -------------------  -------------------  ---------
     1  TV        Somewhere  2018-05-11 16:48:17  2018-05-15 16:48:26       0
     4  MA        Here       2018-05-13 00:00:00  2018-05-13 00:00:00       0
```

It's correct, but what I want is the following result:

```
    id  initials  place                    START                  END  deleted  
------  --------  ---------  -------------------  -------------------  ---------
     1  TV        Somewhere  2018-05-11 16:48:17  2018-05-15 16:48:26          0
     4  MA        Here       2018-05-13 00:00:00  2018-05-13 00:00:00          0
     2  AH        NULL       NULL                 NULL                         0
     3  JE        NULL       NULL                 NULL                         0   
     5  MJ        NULL       NULL                 NULL                         0        
     6  CE        NULL       NULL                 NULL                         0
```

Is it possible to obtain this result with a single request?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the conditions on all but the first table in the `on` clause.  Your `where` clause is turning the outer join into an inner join.

I have some other suggestions:

```
SELECT e.id, e.initials, s.place, s.start, s.end, s.deleted
FROM employees e LEFT JOIN
     schedule_link sl
     ON e.id = sl.id_employee LEFT JOIN
     schedule s
     ON sl.id_schedule = s.id AND s.deleted = 0 AND
        CURDATE() BETWEEN CAST(s.start AS DATE) AND CAST(s.end AS DATE)
WHERE e.deleted = 0;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Backticks just make the query harder to read and write.
- Don't use `start` and `end` as column names (i.e., rename them if you can).  They are keywords (although not reserved), so they have other purposes in a SQL statement.
- I am guessing that `deleted` is numeric.  Don't use single quotes for the comparison (unless the column is really a string).
- `CURDATE()` is already a date.  No need for conversion.
- I don't recommend using `BETWEEN` with dates, because of the possibility of a lingering time component.  However, you are using explicit conversions, so the code unambiguously does what you want (at the risk perhaps of not using an available index).

EDIT:

I see.  Because the date condition is in the third table, not the second, you are getting duplicate rows.  I think this will fix your problem:

```
SELECT e.id, e.initials, ss.place, ss.start, ss.end, ss.deleted
FROM employees e LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT sl.id_employee, s.*
      FROM schedule_link sl JOIN
           schedule s
           ON sl.id_schedule = s.id AND s.deleted = 0
      WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN CAST(s.start AS DATE) AND CAST(s.end AS DATE)
      ) ss
      ON e.id = ss.id_employee
WHERE e.deleted = 0;
```

This will include every employee with no match on the time frame exactly once.  You will still get every record from `schedule` if there are multiple matches.

You can actually express this without a subquery:

```
SELECT e.id, e.initials, s.place, s.start, s.end, s.deleted
FROM employees e LEFT JOIN
     (schedule_link sl JOIN
      schedule s
      ON sl.id_schedule = s.id AND s.deleted = 0 AND
        CURDATE() BETWEEN CAST(s.start AS DATE) AND CAST(s.end AS DATE)
     )
     ON e.id = sl.id_employee
WHERE e.deleted = 0;
```

I find the subquery version easier to follow.

Comment: It works ! Thanks for the advice, I will improve my code!

Comment: It works but I will just have a little extra demand, is it possible that it returns only one "NULL" line per employee with no results? Because if an employee has other records outside of the dates, I get an extra line every time. It works but I do not need all the lines. Just one per employee without records.

Comment: @Joel . . . Just switch to `JOIN`.  If that is the case, you don't want outer joins.

Comment: I'm trying ... but I do not have the result yet.

Comment: JOIN does not seem to work. I would like one row of NULL per employee without records, and if a record is found for an employee, no need to return a row with "NULL". I'm getting tired :))

Comment: . . Any advice ?

Comment: @joel did you try my suggestion with right join and additional null, with isnull() for fields from `schedule` table? I think this may be the result that you are looking for

Comment: Thank you ! That's exactly what I wanted ! Thanks also @SadmirD for the advices ! Your both answers have been very helpful !

Comment: . @Gordon Linoff For future readers of the answer, I think there is a small syntax error in the subquery response here: `ON sl.id_schedule = s.id AND s.deleted = 0 AND`. The last `AND` should not be

Answer (score 1):

My general take (without testing the query since I am away posting from my phone atm):

1. You should use `RIGHT JOIN` on second join in your query.
2. You will also need additional WHERE clause, i.e. `where employees.id is not null`
3. Don't forget to utilize `ifull()` for all fields from schedule table, i.e. `ifnull(schedule_link.id, schedule_link.id, schedule.myfield)`
   Please notice that this should be done for all fields you want to show that come out of `schedule` table in this query

Hope these guidelines will be of any help to you.